# move object relative to screen and not to parent transforms

Tags: javascript, math, 2d, trigonometry

I have two objects - parent and child
the parent has some angle , for example: 90 degrees
the child doesn't have angle, but it's also rotated because it's linked to it's parent transforms.

now I need to move the child 100px in the x Axis and -200px in the y Axis , 
but because the parent has angle, the child moved in the wrong directions.
actually, it is the right directions relative to the parent transforms, but I need to move the child relative to the screen.

I need help with the math...

html

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

style

```
#parent { 
    background: red;
    position:   absolute; 
    left:       0px; 
    top:        0px; 
    width:      150px;
    height:     250px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 75px 200px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(300px,160px) rotate(90deg);
    }

#child { 
    background: green;
    position:   absolute; 
    left:       0px; 
    top:        0px; 
    width:      90px;
    height:     120px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 90px 20px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(100px,-200px);
    }
```

thanks

Comment: How are you doing the transformations, css, canvas, svg? Please show the code you have used for the transformations.

Comment: the transformations is in css , I just updated my question with code example, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you have seen rotating an element rotates the frame of reference for the element.

[image]

In the above diagram the purple axes are the frame of reference for the red rectangle and the green child after a rotation theta clockwise.

You want to move the green rectangle relative to the screen (blue axes), ie translate using the orange vectors.

Given the wanted translation (x,y) relative to screen axes you need to find the translation (xtranslate,ytranslate) relative to the purple axes.

Using the formulas in the diagram with x=100, y=-200 gives xtranslate=-200, ytranslate=-100

Note also that since translate is a move from current position by an amount transforming the origin makes no difference.

So code for child becomes

```
#child { 
    background: green;
    position:   absolute; 
    left:       0px; 
    top:        0px; 
    width:      90px;
    height:     120px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-200px,-100px);
    }
```